# Zend_Test_PHPUnit how to print exception/output?

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

How can I echo a html/xml output from a controller action in my test case?

Here is my testcase:

```
public function testCreateAccountIsASuccessfulRequest()
{
    $this->dispatch('/v2/user/create-account');

    $this->assertFalse($this->response->isException());

    $this->assertNotRedirect();
}
```

Which prints this in commandline:

```
test# /usr/local/bin/phpunit --verbose Controllers_UserControllerTest.php
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

F

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 12.50Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) Controllers_UserControllerTest::testCreateAccountIsASuccessfulRequest
Failed asserting that true is false.

/path/to/tests/Controllers/UserControllerTest.php:17
/usr/local/bin/phpunit:46

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
test#
```

I am not sure what is the actual exception. How to see it? Also, how can I see the actual output of the controller action? So HTML/XML it sends to browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

God I am slow today:

```
public function testCreateAccountIsASuccessfulRequest()
{
    $this->dispatch('/v2/user/create-account');

    echo $this->getResponse()->getBody();

    $this->assertFalse($this->response->isException());

    $this->assertNotRedirect();
}
```